# Android default browser crashes on accessing specific page (no error message)

Tags: browser

When I access this page from my default Android browser:
http://blog.mylookout.com/blog/2011/12/06/carrieriq/

it loads up fine, but:

1. If I click / tap / double-tap anywhere on this page, it exits
2. If I browse up and down, its fine.
3. If I pinch / expand anywhere on the page, it exits.
4. (Only once) I left it alone for a while and the browser exited on its own.

No default settings have been changed. I have lookout (free) installed on a 2.3.3 HTC Incredible S phone.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same on my Desire S. Seems to be a bug in [Skia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skia_Graphics_Engine) font metrics calculation.

All I could get from the crash was that it is in:

```
SkPaint::getFontMetrics(SkPaint::FontMetrics*, float) const
```